# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==2.0.1 (from versions: none) when trying to install Stable Diffusion A1111

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, stable-diffusion, generative-art

I am trying to install Stable Diffusion using A1111. I am following https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/discussions/5461 for instructions.

I am on MacBook Pro M1

After 5th step it gives the error

```
Installing torch and torchvision
Collecting torch==2.0.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==2.0.1 (from versions: none)
```

I think brew has installed python v3.11. So I tried to unistall it. Install Python v3.10.6 and delete the venv folder and tried again but no luck.